# how to push sub array object into an a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi all i am using javascript i am trying to push object values into one array here i attached my code

```
var data = [{
            BuildingID: "56", FloorId: "65", volume: [{

                one: 12,
                two: 15,
                three: 12
            }]
        }]

var MainInfo=[];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var obj = {}
                obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
                obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
                obj.volume = data[i].volume[0];
                MainInfo.push(obj);
  
            }
```

it's working but not fully applicable here i mentioned the excepted output what should i need

## Current output

[image]

## Expected output

[image]

Note:in data volume is dynamic help how to do this

Comment: (It is so nice to finally meet JavaScript in person) :-)

Comment: i have updated my question:) @ trincot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop volume and get keys

```js
var data = [{
            BuildingID: "56", FloorId: "65", volume: [{

                one: 12,
                two: 15,
                three: 12
            }]
        }];

var MainInfo=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var obj = {};
      obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
      obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
     
      for(var j in data[i].volume[0]){
     
        obj[j]= data[i].volume[0][j];
      }
      MainInfo.push(obj);

  }
            
            console.log(MainInfo);
```

Comment: It is usually a good idea to skip potential inherited properties with a `hasOwnProperty` check or an equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

```js
var data = [
 {
  BuildingID : "56",
  FloorId : "65",
  volume : [
   {
    one : 12,
    two : 15,
    three : 12
   }
  ]
 }
];
var MainInfo = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 var obj = {};
 obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
 obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[i].volume[0]).forEach(function (key) {
   obj[key] = data[i].volume[0][key];
 });
 MainInfo.push(obj);
}
console.log(MainInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of correct answers already present however you can use ES6 Arrow function to achieve this with minimum syntax.

```
var MainInfo = data.map( x=>{ return {
        "BuildingID" : x.BuildingID,
        "FloorId" : x.FloorId,
        "one" : x.volume[0]["one"],
        "two" : x.volume[0]["two"],
        "three" : x.volume[0]["three"],
    }})
```

More about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Object.key()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGmsT27qjUAhVKNo8KHa8pBlYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw&sig2=ZQ0OLXWKBSBtjhr_tJp2LQ) and [`Object.values()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4_pqz8KjUAhXFtY8KHaO0CawQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_objects%2FObject%2Fvalues&usg=AFQjCNE5UlL1cEh99fUgeunohGICKbz8Ew&sig2=myUsqzDx-Aq_EAaEM4CNEw) function  .And [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7m_ak76jUAhUEtY8KHeydCCAQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNHYjVYqeuypZH7lxBPKNG7LM-OBOg&sig2=i9xMzgOAyuawNPwZxruwoA) used for iterate the array .Don't hardcore with `volume[0]` .batter iterate with forEach

```js
var data = [{ BuildingID: "56", FloorId: "65", volume: [{ one: 12, two: 15,   three: 12}] }]

var MainInfo=[];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var obj = {}
                obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
                obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
                data[i].volume.forEach(function(a,c){
                Object.keys(data[i].volume[c]).forEach(function(a,b){
                  obj[a] = Object.values(data[i].volume[c])[b]
                })
                })
                MainInfo.push(obj);
            }
            console.log(MainInfo)
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the point of using `Object.values` could be, when you can directly access the original object, especially given that `Object.values` support is very limited.

Comment: @jcaron For op requirement `Object.values` is enough .`Object.value` array is same length of the `object.key` array that why i  was used .and have same position of the value with respected  key array

Comment: Using `Object.values` overcomplicates things for no reason. You write `Object.values(data[i].volume[c])[b]` when you could write `data[i].volume[c][a]`. Also, there are lots of browsers not supporting it.

Comment: Also you're re-using the same variable (`a`)  in two nested loops, which is prone to confusion. And your indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this expected output just replace the 2nd part by

```
var MainInfo=[];
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var obj = {}
            obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
            obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
            obj.one = data[i].volume[0].one;
            obj.three = data[i].volume[0].three;
            obj.two = data[i].volume[0].two;

            MainInfo.push(obj);

        }
```

Comment: Note:in data volume is dynamic help how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this one:

```
function copyProperties(sourceObject, destinationObject)
{
    var k;
    for (k in sourceObject)
    {
       if (sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(k))
         destinationObject[k] = sourceObject[k];
    }
}
```

Note that you haven't quite described what should happen if there's more than one object in the `volume` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for assigning all properties to another object.

```js
var data = [{ BuildingID: "56", FloorId: "65", volume: [{ one: 12, two: 15, three: 12 }] }],
    mainInfo = [],
    i, obj;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj = {}
  obj.BuildingID = data[i].BuildingID;
  obj.FloorId = data[i].FloorId;
  mainInfo.push(Object.assign(obj, data[i].volume[0]));
}

console.log(mainInfo);
```

Comment: Note that `Object.assign` is not supported by IE or the majority of Android browsers, you'll need a polyfill for those.

Comment: @jcaron, right, but the new standard is ES6 with `Object.assign`. it is still possible to iterate wanted properties and assign by hand, but to know, theres a new method to directly assign a whole bunch of properties, it is an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use `$.extend(obj, volume[0])`